# Combine/append multiple excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

I am new in python and I am trying to combine/append multiple excel with the same table structure and I am taking all the excel sheet tab named "Data" with just the specific column.

However, I am getting "TypeError: append() got multiple values for argument 'ignore_index'". Seek for advise on how to fix this issue with my code below?

Expected result: I just want to combine/append all the excel file from the tab named "Data" and with the specific column into one master excel.

```
  import pandas as pd
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, 'S:\\19 Performance Analytics\ETL Data Extraction\\PyCr')
    
    # MYOS Resort Q1
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\jiacheng.heng\OneDrive - Shangri-La Group\NOVA\Arrival Check Tracker\CT2 Arrival Check Report\2023\2023 - Q1 - MYSLOS RESORT Arrival Checks.xlsx")
    columns = ['Report Pull Out Date (DD-MMM-YY)','Property','Confirmation No.','Guest Name','Arrival','Departure','Rate Code','Source'
               ,'Arr. Transfer Type','Dep. Transfer Type','Status','Agent Initial','Remark','Completion Date','Completion Month','Received Month'
               ,'Arrival Month','Tasks Status','AHT','Pending Aging','SLA']
    df=df.append(xls.parse('Data',usecols= columns))
    
    # MYOS Resort Q2
    combdf = pd.DataFrame()
    xls1 = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\jiacheng.heng\OneDrive - Shangri-La Group\NOVA\Arrival Check Tracker\CT2 Arrival Check Report\2023\2023 - Q2 - MYSLOS RESORT Arrival Checks.xlsx")
    columns = ['Report Pull Out Date (DD-MMM-YY)','Property','Confirmation No.','Guest Name','Arrival','Departure','Rate Code','Source'
               ,'Arr. Transfer Type','Dep. Transfer Type','Status','Agent Initial','Remark','Completion Date','Completion Month','Received Month'
               ,'Arrival Month','Tasks Status','AHT','Pending Aging','SLA']
    combdf=combdf.append(xls1.parse('Data',usecols= columns))
    
    # MYOS City Q1 & Q2
    combdf2 = pd.DataFrame()
    xls2 = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\jiacheng.heng\OneDrive - Shangri-La Group\NOVA\Arrival Check Tracker\CT2 Arrival Check Report\2023\2023 - Q1 & Q2 - MYSLOS CITY Arrival Checks.xlsx")
    columns = ['Report Pull Out Date (DD-MMM-YY)','Property','Confirmation No.','Guest Name','Arrival','Departure','Rate Code','Source'
               ,'Arr. Transfer Type','Dep. Transfer Type','Status','Agent Initial','Remark','Completion Date','Completion Month','Received Month'
               ,'Arrival Month','Tasks Status','AHT','Pending Aging','SLA']
    combdf2=combdf2.append(xls2.parse('Data',usecols= columns))
    
    # HKOS Q1 & Q2
    combdf3 = pd.DataFrame()
    xls3 = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\jiacheng.heng\OneDrive - Shangri-La Group\NOVA\Arrival Check Tracker\CT1 Arrival Check Report\2023\2023 - Q1 & Q2 - HKOS Arrival Checks.xlsx")
    columns = ['Report Pull Out Date (DD-MMM-YY)','Property','Confirmation No.','Guest Name','Arrival','Departure','Rate Code','Source'
               ,'Arr. Transfer Type','Dep. Transfer Type','Status','Agent Initial','Remark','Completion Date','Completion Month','Received Month'
               ,'Arrival Month','Tasks Status','AHT','Pending Aging','SLA']
    combdf3=combdf3.append(xls3.parse('Data',usecols= columns))
    
    # HKOS Q3 & Q4
    combdf4 = pd.DataFrame()
    xls4 = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\jiacheng.heng\OneDrive - Shangri-La Group\NOVA\Arrival Check Tracker\CT1 Arrival Check Report\2023\2023 - Q3 & Q4 - HKOS Arrival Checks.xlsx")
    columns = ['Report Pull Out Date (DD-MMM-YY)','Property','Confirmation No.','Guest Name','Arrival','Departure','Rate Code','Source'
               ,'Arr. Transfer Type','Dep. Transfer Type','Status','Agent Initial','Remark','Completion Date','Completion Month','Received Month'
               ,'Arrival Month','Tasks Status','AHT','Pending Aging','SLA']
    combdf4=combdf4.append(xls4.parse('Data',usecols= columns))
    
    combdf=combdf.append(df,combdf2,combdf3,combdf4, ignore_index=True)
    combdf = combdf.iloc[: , :-1]
    
    
    # Import the data into excel file
    combdf.to_excel(r"S:\19 Performance Analytics\NOVA\Appended Arrival Checks.xlsx", index=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) method, you can read the excel file. You get the individual created dataframes. Taking xls and xls1 as an example, each one will be a dataframe, after you use the [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method. That you will be able to join the dataframes after reading, in the end to transform everything into a single file you use [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) , like you did. It will greatly reduce your code. It will be simpler for you to understand.

Comment: I am very new in Python, could you share how you will write the code to reach the expected result?